# Docker Network Troubles with very simple docker-compose setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-network

I'm still trying to learn how to work on docker cause since I started to work on Mac OS X, and everything has been a pain in the ass compared to how well worked on Linux.

I'm trying this tutorial but I'm stuck after running the php + apache service with docker compose, I can't connect to the container to check my files on my deployed web environment: [docker compose tutorial](https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/setting-up-a-development-environment-with-docker-compose)

The container runs ok and if I do a `docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"` I recieve the ip **172.20.0.2**.

If I put this ip in my browser or ping it , I don't get any response.

> Yes, I setting 172.20.0.2:8080

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  php:
    build: apache-php
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    volumes:
      - ./apache-php/www:/var/www/html
```

What I've tried:

1. In /etc/hosts set 172.20.0.2 to a domain like docker.web
2. Removing the ports from docker-compose.yml
3. Trying to access through localhost:8080

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried adding `network_mode: host` to `services: php:` in docker-compose file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ports` settings controls which ports are mapped back to your host. Have you tried visiting `localhost:8080` in your browser?

EDIT: Mapping port `80` from the container to the host is what solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, I got no response back neither.

Comment: Which command did you use to start the container? Can you post the output of `docker-compose ps`?

Comment: Hi, I'm using docker-compose up to start the container. My docker file has this: 

`FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli`

And the output from **docker-compose ps** is:
web_environment_php_1   docker-php-entrypoint apac ...   Up      80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp

Comment: Try adding "80:80" to the `ports` setting and visiting `localhost:80`. It looks like the container is exposing the web content on port 80, so you need to map it back to the host. If your host already has port 80 bound, try another one like "8088:80" then visit `localhost:8088`.

Comment: It worked! setting 80:80 on docker-compose.yml now worked. I also managed to find a background apache working and using my port 80, that's why I also tried the "8080:80" conf and worked too.  Tho I didn't understand why this is happenning... 

in ports: - "<first port>: <second port>"

The first port is the one I want to use in my host machine and the 80 is the port that the container will use?

Comment: That's correct - see the docs here for more info: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports